# Python: only replace a string in specific location if the string appears several time in a line

Tags: python, replace

I have file, in a certain line, there's string, looks like this,

A, 20140101, B, 20, C

I want to replace "20" with "30.1" and write into new file

My code is:

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')

f2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')

for line in f1:

    f2.write(line.replace('20', '30.1'))

f1.close()

f2.close()
```

After I do this, the 20 in 20140101 will show as 30.1140101.

How can I just replace my 4th string: 20.

Comment: I presume  20 can appear anywhere in the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the comma and a space to only replace 20 when it has a space before and a comma after:

```
s = 'A, 20140101, B, 20, C'
print(s.replace(" 20,"," 30.1,"))
A, 20140101, B, 30.1, C


In [6]: s = 'A, 20140101, B, 20, C'

In [7]: s.replace(" 20,"," 30.1,")
Out[7]: 'A, 20140101, B, 30.1, C'

In [8]: s = 'A, 120, 140101, B, 20, C'

In [9]: s.replace(" 20,"," 30.1,")
Out[9]: 'A, 120, 140101, B, 30.1, C'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`

```
import re
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(re.sub(r'\b20\b', r'30.1', line))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

`\b` Word boundary which usually  matches between a word and non-word character. So `\b20\b` would matches the exact number `20`

Comment: if i want to use line_split[4] to represent 20, they are equal here. \b does not work. what boundary should I use? thanks!

Comment: This would work for most cases, it won't care about the location of `20`. ie, it works if the input string is `20, foo, bar, foobar`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I just replace my 4th string?

Python knows nothing about the semantic meaning of your lines. When *you* look at your file, you know that each line contains five pieces of information. But as far as Python is concerned, each line is *one* string, not five. If there are discrete fields in each line which must be handled differently, you should handle them explicitly yourself. Since this appears to be a CSV file, you can look into the `csv` module, or simply use `split`:

```
for line in f1:
    parts = line.split(',')  # Split the line by comma
    if parts[3] == '20':  # Perform modifications to a specific field
        parts[3] = '30.1'
    f2.write(','.join(parts))  # Rejoin the fields, using a comma as the delimiter
```